# creating static library for iphone-device issue

Tags: iphone, static-libraries, device

I'm creating static library for sharing code(iphone)for that i'm following the 
[below link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)

It works fine in simulator but,when i tried to port with device it show me an error.What all are changes i should do to change from simulator to device.

Anyone please help me out to do this..
[image: This the Error Message i'm getting while try to port with device]

Thank You

Comment: Please include the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the library by setting project for device as well as simulator.
Sometimes you did for simulator,and forgot to do for device.In that time you will get error like that.

Comment: :yes friend..you are correct.We need to build our library with distribution mode.Thank you so much